# Can create problems ( like crashes) to work on a Pycharm project while another project has a script running?

Tags: python, pycharm

like i write above, i'm running a python script that has an ETA of 37 hours, and I need to continue working. Is there any problem if I start another Pycharm session in another window and I for example run another script? wuould it create problems like crash, memory limit or something like that?

My laptop has an i7 4710HQ, dedicated Gforce GTX850M and 8gb of RAM
the script is just a simple **scrape** of a website, but having ban problem i set a 5 second sleep after every request. but i have to made 20,000 requests...

thanks in advance!

Comment: Memory could always be an issue, but everything else should be fine. _the script is just a simple scrap of a website, but having ban problem i set a 5 second sleep after every request. but i have to made 20,000 requests..._ Are you taking advantage of a persistent connection? There are ways of getting around blocking attempts, although the best thing is probably to take the hint ;)

Comment: @AMC unfortunately I'm not using a persistent connection, to be honest I'm reading just now about it.. it there a way to use it in requests?

Comment: You don't really need to open another Pycharm. You can just run another script and will start running in a separate tab. Read more [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002518180-Run-multiple-run-windows-for-different-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

If you have two instances of PyCharm running, unless the 2nd instance actually crashes the O/S (Blue Screen or equivalent), that shouldn't impact the 1st instance in anyway.

They run in seaprate processes which are almost sandboxes the only common thing they share is the initial executable file, and the file system and the O/S. If they are in different projects then they only share the PyCharm system settings.

You could even cause Python to segfault (rare but it does happen) and that wont effect your long running PyCharm application - also remember that your applications were started by PyCharm, but they aren't running in the PyCharm process. So in fact what you have is two Pycharm processes each one with at least one child process which is your running application.